# jQuery FadeIn from left to right

Tags: jquery, fadein

In my jQuery I fadein a div with an ID. I want that the fadein "moves" from the left to the right.

My snippet so far:

```
$('#content').hide().fadeIn(1500);
```

Who can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Check This http://stackoverflow.com/a/625192/1961192

Answer (score 4):

```
 $("#content").hide().show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1500);
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. Uncaught TypeError: k.easing[this.easing] is not a function
    at init.run (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#content').hide().fadeIn(function(){ 
    $('#content').animate({
        left: "80px"
    }, 500); 
},1500).css('left' ,'0');
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be harder to achieve than it sounds. And even harder if you need to support older browsers like IE8.

The most practical solution I can think of is to use an overlay element that is the same colour as the background, but with a gradient rather than a solid background colour.

The gradient would have the solid colour for at least the size of the element being hidden so that it appears to be just showing the background colour, but would have a hidden portion that extends beyond the borders of the element, and fade out to transparent in that hidden portion.

Then it's a simple case of animating the overlay so that the gradient is gradually exposed, revealing the content behind it.

You wouldn't use the normal `fadeIn()` function at all. Even though it would look like a sideways fade-in, from a technical perspective it would be like an effect to slide a card off the top of an element to reveal it.

It may be tricky to get right in old versions of IE, which use a proprietary feature for gradients. It ought to be possible in theory, but IE8's `filter` gradients have quite a few quirks that might catch you out if you're trying to do 'clever' stuff with them like this.

I don't have time to write a working prototype for you, but hopefully that gives you enough of a starter to get going with writing it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a ***fast*** an ***easy*** way:

`$("#ID").css({"position":"relative","opacity": 0, "left":"+=100"});
 $("#ID").animate({left:0, opacity:1},2000);`

You need to specify `"opacity" :0, "position": "relative"(or Absolute)` in the CSS or by tweaking it with JQuery. Like I've done.

This code **moves** the object *100px* from it's original position. And then back again while fading in.

**Good Luck!**

Answer (score 1):

//This is what you want

```
var $marginLefty =    $("#content"); // your selector here

$marginLefty.animate({
     height:'toggle',width:'toggle',
      marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
        $marginLefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    });
```

Sample Example edited below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){

var $marginLefty =    $("#content"); // your selector here

$marginLefty.animate({
     height:'toggle',width:'toggle',
      marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
        $marginLefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    });
  });
});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<button>Start Animation</button>

<div id="content" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. A question: Now the element disappears. How can I reverse the "animation" that the element comes from "outside" to the content?

Comment: Simple. Call the same function again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS transitions, combining two of them, width and opacity.

```
-webkit-transition: width 500ms ease-in, opacity 1.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: width 500ms ease-in, opacity 1.5s ease-out;
-o-transition: width 500ms ease-in, opacity 1.5s ease-out;
transition: width 500ms ease-in, opacity 1.5s ease-out;
```

To let the content stay at the same place see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LLn311un/1/

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the animate.css library

Simply link the css file to your page:

`<link href= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

You can also download the file and serve it locally.

Then just add the classes "animated slideInLeft" to your element.

`$('#content').show().addClass('animated slideInLeft');`

You can check the documentation here: https://animate.style/